# Split a Dataframe row into 2 rows if a cell value is a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a DF, which looks like this:

```
id      value     country
215     x, y      UK
360     z         Spain
```

I'd like to split it into this form:

```
id      value     country
215     x         UK
215     y         UK
360     z         Spain
```

So, I want to duplicate the rows for each row where df['value'] has more than one value split with comma.

I know I have to split it into a list:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
```

What do you do next to duplicate the row the way I want to?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57122617/9081267) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. It uses the str.split functions on the ['value'] Series:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [215, 360], 'value':  ['x, y', 'z'], 'country': ["UK", "Spain"]})
df["value"] = df["value"].str.split(pat=",")
print(df.explode("value"))
```

Result:

```
    ID value country
0  215     x      UK
0  215     y      UK
1  360     z   Spain
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for a swift response! Naming this 'explode' is really funny.